# How does class casting work?

Tags: casting, classcastexception

Consider c1 is the base class of c3. The below code works perfectly.

```
    c1 obj1=new c3();
    c3 obj2=(c3)obj1;
```

But, There is a ClassCastException in the below one

```
    c1 obj1=new c1();
    c3 obj3=(c3)obj1;
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening is that you are creating obj1 as an instance of c1, and then trying to cast it to class further down the inheritance chain than c1.

In your first example, c1 is a base type of c3 and so you can create an instance of c3 where the type is c1..that's fine. c3 is a child of c1 and so inherits all its properties and methods.

In the 2nd example, however, you are creating an instance of c1 with a type of c1. You are then trying to cast it to its child. A child class may have additional properties and methods that the parent doesn't have.

To summarise, a child can be of its parent type and cast to it, however, a parent cannot be its child and cannot be cast as such.

If you need further clarification, let me know.

Comment: That helped me a lot. Thank you :)

Comment: @ Literallyluke ,can you also please include the difference between the 'type' and 'instance of'? What do they actually infer?
For eg.,

        c1 obj = new c3();

Here c1 is the 'type' and c3 is the 'instance'

Comment: @ShreeNaath A type is just telling the compiler what class to use (c1, Integer, String, Animal etc). Consider it a placeholder for an object note yet created. The instance is the created accessible object (c1(), 1, "hello", Dog() etc) each of which has its own values for properties.

Comment: I'll rephrase what u've said. Please do correct me of I am wrong. The type tells the compiler at what class or interface to look for the methods and the instance class tells the compiler what method definition to take while executing it.

Comment: Pretty much. Except the instance is a construction of the class (if the class is a blueprint then the instance is what was built based on that blueprint)